# How to checkout to a new branch with Pygithub?

Tags: python, github, github-api, pygithub

This is what I have learned,

```
g = Github("user", "pass")
repoName = "apiTest"
print "Get all repos:"
for repo in g.get_user().get_repos():
print "\t%s" % repo.name

print "<--------------------------------------------------->"

print "Get all branches in repo %s:" % repoName
for branch in g.get_user().get_repo(repoName).get_branches():
print "\t%s" % branch.name

print "<--------------------------------------------------->"

print "Get last commit message in repo %s:" % repoName
branch = g.get_user().get_repo(repoName).get_branch("dev")
lastCommit = branch._commit.value.commit
print "\t%s" % lastCommit._message.value
print "\t%s"

print "<--------------------------------------------------->"
fc = repo.update_file("/README.md", "testing PyGithub", "test commit", fc.sha)
print fc
```

but I 'd like to know how to checkout to a new branch. I didn't find any example online. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 24):

You can use the PyGithub create_git_ref function to create a new branch. Using your above example:

```
g = Github("user", "pass")
repoName = "apiTest"
source_branch = 'master'
target_branch = 'newfeature'

repo = g.get_user().get_repo(repoName)
sb = repo.get_branch(source_branch)
repo.create_git_ref(ref='refs/heads/' + target_branch, sha=sb.commit.sha)
```

Comment: Given that the source_branch may be 'master' or 'main', you can get the name programatically with repo.default_branch.